# How do elements absolutely positioned stretch super scrollView? react-native

Tags: react-native

Here is the render function:

```
React.Children.forEach(children, (item, index) => {
  let image = React.cloneElement(item, {
        style: [item.props.style, styles.image],
      });
  items.push(
    <TouchableHighlight key={'touch_'+index} style={[styles.item]}>
      {image}
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
});

return (
  <Modal visible={this.props.isOpen}>
    <ScrollView
      pagingEnabled={true}
      horizontal={true}>
        {items}
    </ScrollView>
  </Modal>
);
```

and Here are the element's styles:

`item: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    margin: 0,
    width: WINDOW_WIDTH,
    height: WINDOW_HEIGHT,
  }`

Each `item` is absolutely positioned, but I can't scroll the `scrollView`, just like there is only one page(item)，because all of the images overlapped

Comment: Thank you for correcting my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my fault. I set wrong position `attribute` in `React.Children.forEach`. I was misguided by `absolute position` element in `css`, these elements can't stretch super element. Actually elements absolutely positioned in ReactNative  can stretch `scrollview`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a small change

**HTML**:

```
<ScrollView pagingEnable={true} horizontal={true}>
  <div class="item">{items}</div>
</ScrollView>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.item{
 position: relative;
}
ScrollView{
 position: absolute;  /*mentioned in the question */
}
```

If you are giving more codelines , we can find a better solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I showed more code just now,but my code is react-native, obviously your code is font-end code.^_^